# What is the modern classic by Hurwitz stated in a Product Flyer of Springer?

Tags: book-recommendation

In the [Product Flyer of the famous book *What is Mathematics*](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/productFlyer/productFlyer_978-3-540-63777-6.pdf?SGWID=0-0-1297-1384988-0), it is said that the book by Courant and Robbins is the third of the "Golden Oldies" combing with the books by Rademacher/Toeplitz and Hurwitz( "Dritte Staffel der "Golden Oldies" zusammen mit den beiden
modernen Klassikern von Rademacher/Toeplitz und Hurwitz").

It is clear that the book by Rademacher/Toeplitz is *The Enjoyment of Math* (English Translation). I wonder what is the book by Hurwitz.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat likely they mean his [Lectures on Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387962360), which was a classic once upon a time. Although he was a very prolific mathematician, Hurwitz wrote very few books --- in fact, as far as I can tell, this is the only book he ever wrote.

Comment: There's also *Vorlesungen über Allgemeine Funktionentheorie und Elliptische Funktionen* by Hurwitz with additions by Courant: http://www.amazon.com/Vorlesungen-Allgemeine-Funktionentheorie-Elliptische-Funktionen/dp/3662317699/

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The point is that the style of these two books is quite different from the style of _What is Mathematics_ and _The Enjoyment of Math_. Moreover, according to the [Obituary of Hurwitz(http://www.numbertheory.org/obituaries/LMS/hurwitz/page5.html),   the only publication in book form of Hurwitz is a reprint of one of his papers on _Quaternion Theory of Numbers_. @Hans Lundmark

Comment: Yes, it is a bit weird. Maybe they just meant somebody else but confused the names...